# Send Push Notifications from Laravel Server to Android App via Firebase

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

is it possible to send a push notification to android but through laravel based dashboard, rather than through the firebase console?

And if possible, what are the steps?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd check some of the questions and answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-cloud-messaging%5D+%5Blaravel%5D+send This question for example, seems to go a long way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554177/laravel-fcm-send-data-payload-only as does this: https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase

Answer (score 1):

You can create helper function for it.

Try this:-

```
function notifications($token=null,$title=null,$message=null,$user_id=null)
{
    $path_to_firebase_cm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'to' => $token,
        'notification' => array('title' => $title, 'body' => $message, 'sound' => 'default', 'click_action' => 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK', 'icon' => 'fcm_push_icon'),
        'data' => array('title' => $title, 'body' => $message, 'sound' => 'default', 'icon' => 'fcm_push_icon'),
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key=' . 'Your-fcm-key',
        'Content-Type:application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_firebase_cm); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use this function

```
public function send_fcm_notification($title,$body,$target,$chid){
  define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'ENTER_API_KEY_HERE' );
  $fcmMsg = array(
             'title' => $title,
             'body' => $body,
             'channelId' => $chid
            );
  $fcmFields = array(
                'to' => $target, //tokens sending for notification
                'notification' => $fcmMsg,
               );
  $headers = array(
                 'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                 'Content-Type: application/json'
               );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fcmFields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
//echo $result . "\n\n";
}
```